# Подовження Й або ВІЙЯ

Tags: фонетика, морфологія

Існує слово [*війя*](http://sum.in.ua/s/vijja), котре, на відміну змосковчених *майя*, *фойє* і подібних, питоме і, схоже, далебі подовження.

Як воно відбулося? Як і де можливе подібне подовження **й**? Особливо цїкаво й те, що [більшість](/q/4359/) джерел взагалі не вказують на можливе подовження **й**, як з иншими звуками в словах *життя*, *суддя*, *подовження* і подальші.

Comment: У [вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE): "Назви інших елементів упряжі також можуть мати дуже давнє походження: так, від пра-і.е. *ei-/*-oi («дишель», «жердина для запрягу») через прасл. *oie походить укр. війя[4]" з посиланням на "Етимологічний словник української мови : у 7 т. : т. 1 : А — Г / Ін-т мовознавства ім. О. О. Потебні АН УРСР ; укл.: Р. В. Болдирєв та ін ; редкол.: О. С. Мельничук (гол. ред.) та ін. — К. : Наукова думка, 1982. — 632 с."

Comment: Ну, фактично тут не відбувалось подовження, адже й не має потреби асимілювати й уподібнюватись самому собі. Тобто, це звичайний збіг однакових приголосних на межі корінь/суфікс, яке виникло після занепаду ь: войьйе > віййа.